# GWTP unit testing using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, mockito, gwt-platform

I am trying to use Mockito to test my GWTP application.

I am trying to Mock my View,Proxy,Placemanager and eventbus.
I tried using 
@Mock
AbcView abc;

and Abcview abc = Mockito.mock(AbcView.class);

However every time the mocked view is instantiated as null.
How shall i address the same?
Once the view is mocked i will be able go on with testing my presenter class, as the constructor of presenter has following code:
getView().setUiHandlers( this );

so until view is instantiated properly null pointer exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your test using the `MockitoJUnitRunner` runner?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private List list;

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        list.add(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: or alternatively to run static method: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`

Comment: Try to run the ExampleTest I posted to see if everything is working well with a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Sydney's response, you also need o make sure that `AbcView.class` is not final.  I forget whether a final class results in a null or a runtime error, but that can be a cause for some sort of unexpected behavior -- one way or another, the mocking doesn't work.  And if the class is not final, you need to make sure that any methods you stub on that mock are not final.

Comment: neither the class nor the methods are final

Comment: try including some simple code snippets, being sure to include the @Setup if you have one, the test method, and the general object definition and available constructors for your presenter.  Oh, and what version of mockito you are using.  The latest version supports constructor injection, but earlier versiond so not.

Comment: I am using Mockito 1.9.0. One thing which i forgot to mention is that i am extending my Testclas with GWTTestCase so i am using gwtSetup method to do the test setup. Would that make any difference? I want my test to be GWTJunit test case only.